# "Did you know you could do that?" Is "could" acceptable and why?

Tags: modal-verbs, questions

Is it correct to use "could" here?

> Did you know you could do that?

What grammar rule do I have to look at to reliably answer those questions myself?

Comment: I'm sure it *is* "grammatical", but I don't suppose most native speakers would be able to say exactly which contexts allow/require ***could*** as opposed to ***can***. For many people and/or many contexts, they're interchangeable (meaning the *hearer* won't distinguish a difference in meaning or "correctness" any more than the *speaker*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When speaking of the present, or without reference to time (in general), the words are interchangeable to the native speaker. Using the word ***could*** as opposed to ***can*** is only more appropriate when the speaker wishes to emphasize that the capability being discussed isn't recent.

> Let's discuss two employees: Goofus and Gallant. Goofus received a new clearance on his badge two months ago. Gallant just received that same clearance today and, unlike Goofus, took the time to read the instructions that came with it. It is raining very hard. As Goofus heads toward the street to walk into the building through the pouring rain, Gallant stops him, "Goofus, ***didn't you know you could use the covered entrance with the new clearance***?"

Once again, the word ***could*** could be replaced with ***can*** without making the sentence ungrammatical, but by using the word **could**, Gallant is trying to drive home to Goofus that the capability is one he's had *for quite some time*.

So, to answer your questions in order:

> Is it correct to use "could" here?

**Answer:** Absolutely

> What grammar rule do I have to look at to reliably answer those questions myself?

**Answer:** Tense. When the capability isn't something recent, you ***could*** use the (simple) past tense, but otherwise, you ***can*** use whichever word you wish.